# Stop ethernet from automatically reconnecting

Tags: networking, ethernet, virtualbox-networking

I have a dual Ethernet connection setup on my computer running Ubuntu 18 in a VM from virtual box.  I need to disconnect one or the other occasionally because of lack of routing in some applications.  Problem is that whenever I disconnect Eth0, the OS will automatically create a connection, "eth0."  If I delete or disconnect from "eth0," the OS will reconnect.

I am thinking this is part of autoethernet but not sure how to stop it.

Comment: Disconnect network connections for the *guest* using the vbox settings on the *host*. VirtualBox application (*host*) --> Network --> Adapter *N* --> Advanced. Use the 'cable connected' checkbox to virtually plug/unplug the connections you want.

Answer (score 0):

Is this for one of the desktop distributions, or for server? For desktop, open the NetworkManager, click the "Configure Network Connections" icon. You will see all your interfaces. In the General Settings tab, there is a check box for "Automatically connect to this network when it is available". Uncheck it!

For server, just make sure there is no `auto eth0` line (possibly along with other interfaces) in `/etc/network/interfaces` or any of its subdirectories.

Comment: Its a desktop, ubuntu 18.  I believe gnome has dropped the gui for NetworkManager.  SO not sure where to find "Automatically connect to this network when it is available"